# How Firebase Performance Monitoring intercepts outgoing http requests in android?

Tags: android, firebase, performance, bytecode, firebase-performance

From firebase's help doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/network-traces?platform=android , it states

> For all app types, Performance Monitoring automatically collects a trace for each network request issued by your app, called an HTTP/S network request trace
> Performance Monitoring automatically collects metrics for network requests that use the following networking libraries: OkHttp3, Java's URLConnection, Apache HttpClient

How are they tracking the http requests automatically without using any interceptors ? are they using any byte code manipulation to track them ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is using bytecode manipulation on Android.  That's what the plugin does at build time.  It finds all occurrences of API calls that look like HTTP requests (URLConnection, Apache HTTPClient, and OKHTTP), and decorates those calls with an object that monitors their use at runtime.

If you want a deep dive into how that actually works, [watch this talk](https://www.droidcon.com/media-detail?video=362742295).

Comment: Thanks @Doug . Just curious here , is there byte code manipulation for swift & objective c too ? How does firebase automatically tracks URLSession & URLConnection for iOS apps ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately.  iOS doesn't work the same way.

Comment: i've raised it as a separate post  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64542863/how-firebase-performance-monitoring-intercepts-outgoing-http-requests-in-ios) . Kindly check it .